# Netlogo: stopping model when global is constant for X amount of ticks

Tags: netlogo

Currently I am constructing a model on opinion dynamics and want the model to stop automatically when a certain global variable `global-participation-rate` remains unchanged for X amount of ticks. I probably should include something like

```
if stop-ticking? [stop]
```

in my go procedure. With the report looking something like this:

```
to-report stop-ticking?    
 ifelse (??) = ??     [report true] [report false]
end
```

What code should I use to check whether the global remained unchanged for a certain amount of ticks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a new global to keep count.  E.g., (abbreviating `global-participation-rate` to `gpr`):

```
globals [gpr ct-gpr]

to update-gpr
  let old-gpr gpr  ;store old value
  set gpr get-gpr  ;compute new value
  ;increment or reset the counter:
  set ct-gpr ifelse-value (gpr != old-gpr) [1] [1 + ct-gpr]
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a global variable for either the participation-rate or total converted or whatever. Then after your diffusion process, you do something like `let new-adopters <calculation>` and `if-else new-adopters = total-adopters [stop] [set total-adopters new-adopters]`

If you need more than one time point comparison, then you need to create a list rather than a simple value and add the new value to the end of the list and check the end of the list is all the same number.

Comment: How do you create a list with the values of a certain variable over an amount of ticks? Could you give an example to check if the value of a variable is the same as 50 ticks in the past? I'm a bit lost on this one. Thanks!

Comment: Each tick you add the current value to the list